# ggplot geom_smooth can't turn off se for lm method

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

is there an obvious reason as to why I can't turn off the se plotting in geom_smooth with the 'lm' method?

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- seq(1, 10)
a <- 2 * x
b <- 3 * x
df <- data.frame(cbind(x, a, b)) %>% gather(class, y, a:b)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = class)) + geom_point() +
       geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

but this

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- seq(1, 10)
a <- 2 * x
b <- 3 * x
df <- data.frame(cbind(x, a, b)) %>% gather(class, y, a:b)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = class)) + geom_point() +
       geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = 'False')
```

produces the following error:

```
Warning message:
“Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'”
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You want `se = FALSE`.

Comment: I do indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You need to use FALSE or F:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = class)) + geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = F)
```

[image: no se]